# Как построить поле для рисование?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно построить поле в котором можно рисововать и получить информацию о цвете каждого пикселя. Я создал ИИ для определения цифр с помощью MNIST, и хочу сам вводить цифры для определения.

Comment: Ну наверное `tkinter` какой-нибудь нужно использовать

Comment: А есть ли какие то способы получить информацию о цвете пикселя, кроме скриншота?